# Make graph in d3 with google analytics JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I'm currently extracting the amount of sessions by date from the google analytics api.  I turn this data from a basic Javascript array into a JSON.  The JSON data looks like this

`[["20140521","7"],["20140522","5"],["20140523","1"]]`

The date then the amount of sessions.

I'm fairly new to using D3.js but can't seem to find an accurate guide on how to take each object and plot my dates as the x and my sessions as the y.  I'm also aware that I may need to make my data look like this: `["20140521": 7]`  How could I go about doing this?

If somebody could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.  Please let me know if you have any questions!

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to read up more on [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) as `[["20140521","7"],["20140522","5"],["20140523","1"]]` is not JSON, simply an array of arrays. In addition, `["20140521": 7]` is not valid JSON, or a valid Javascript Array for that matter. For d3, you typically want to aim for something along the lines of: `[{date:"20140521", sessions:1}, {date:"20140522", sessions:3}]`

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.  I'm pretty new to this stuff so I appreciate you pointing this out.  Any recommendation on how I can turn my data into the appropriate data like so: [{date:"23234", "sessoins": 1 }]

Comment: No problem, actually my last example isn't valid JSON either! :-). It would need to be `[{"date":"20140521", "sessions":1}, {"date":"20140522", "sessions":3}]`

Comment: Ok so now I'm returning data as `20140521,7 20140522, 5`.  How do I turn that into [{"date":"20140521", "sessions";"7"}, {"date":"20140522", "sessions";"5"}]?

Comment: Actually, your best bet is probably to go with your first schema, the array of arrays. Then you could just apply a map:  `var transformed = [["20140521",7],["20140522",5],["20140523",1]].map(function (d) { return {date: d[0], session:d[1]};})`